# Informatica_adding new fields to query

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Iam new to Informatica,I have to add two new fields(AREA,AMT) to an already existing SQL query in Informatica. After this should I manually add the source qualifier port with these two fields?

What I did was:

1) Changed the query in SQL qualifier in Mapping designer- added the two new fields, saved the mapping

2) Refreshed the workflow in Workflow designer

3) Monitored the result in Workflow Monitor which was successful.

Now, the resulting text file has the new field values but no column header names. Hence the column header values are shifted resulting in column name and value misalignment.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: put your sql queries in question!

Comment: Iam not able to post the query some issue

Comment: You might have a command to generate the header in output file. If so, you have modify that in session properties.

Answer (score 0):

**YES you should manually add the two ports to the Source Qualifier.** The number of fields selected in the SQL query should match the number of ports in the Source qualifier which are linked to the next transformation.

Interestingly Informatica maps the fields from the SQL query to the Source qualifier output links instead of Source Qualifier ports. So the first column in the SQL query gets mapped to the first link, second column to the second link and so on.

For your header issue, you should let us know how you are generating the headers for the output file. If you are using "Use header command output" option in the target file session properties for generating headerthen you have edit the command to create header for there two new ports as well.